# (Android) How to establish peer to peer connection via internet given each device's IP addresses

Tags: android, connection, p2p

I'm trying to send a chunk of data (about 1mb) from an android device to another via internet. Lets say I can get each device's IP address and open a specific socket before making the connection.

I have successfully making this connection via Wi-Fi Direct, however the distance between each device became an issue. Therefore, i need to use internet connection. I hear that WebRTC could make such connection, but it needs me to use STUN/TURN server to get other party IP addresses (which I can get without server).

I expected to have this connection pure peer to peer like Wi-Fi direct (without any use of cloud server). If a server is needed i could make one of the device act like the server.

If anyone could provide me some example of code of how to do this in kotlin, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try out WebRTCs apprtc demo.  There are instructions on how to get and compile the code here https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/

You should be able to see how a data channel is established and how to send/receive that data.

Comment: WebRTC does need a server right? can i transfer those data without server?

Comment: You would need a STUN server to gather IP addresses.  Google does have a free stun server to use.  You would, however need to set up a socket server for your two phones to exchange SDP and Ice candidates in order for them to establish a peer connection and open a data channel.  Once that peer connection is established, your phones would have a p2p connection.